# Weird definition for convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logic

if exists $N\in\mathbb N$ that for all $\varepsilon>0$ so that for all $n>N \,\,$ $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon \Longrightarrow \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}a_{n}=L$

Any ideas on how to prove this definition is equal to the conventional definition of a the limit of sequence?

Comment: The way you write down the above definition, it is certainly not equal to the conventional definition of a limit of a sequence, it is a lot stronger. It reads as "there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that the distance between any later element of the sequence and $L$ is smaller than any $\epsilon >0$". The only number smaller than every $\epsilon >0$ is $0$ itself.

Think about what that means heuristically, then it should dawn on you that this is indeed a much stronger condition than just convergence.

Comment: Why do you think its weird?

Answer (score 1):

The implication is certainly true, but the given condition is not equivalent to the definition of limit. For that condition to hold, the terms of $a_n$ are all equal to $L$ from a certain order on.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Notice that $$\exists N\in\mathbb N: \forall \varepsilon >0, \forall n\in\mathbb N, n\geq N\implies |a_n-L|<\varepsilon $$
means that $a_n=L$ for all $n\geq N$.